# Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup ../@shelf/jest-mongodb/setup.js, reason: Instance Exited before being ready and without throwing an error

Tags: mongodb, jestjs

I'm following the documentation on [jestjs.io](https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb). When I try to run a test I get this error:

`Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - /home/.../node_modules/@shelf/jest-mongodb/setup.js, reason: Instance Exited before being ready and without throwing an error!`

This happened both when I've used typescript and also when I created a simple app using javascript instead:

`package.json:`

```json
{
  "name": "mongojest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.0"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb"
};
```

I haven't made any changes other than the minimum installs to get it running.

Comment: Anything useful in https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb/issues/293 ?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I had a look and tried to make some changes in line with what they're suggesting but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this issue by installing Ubuntu 20.04. I was using the newer Ubuntu 22.04 and it seem to have caused some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I installed typescript in my project. That was enough to run. Follow my configuration files

```js
//package.json

{
  "name": "research-with-programmers-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests --silent --noStackTrace --runInBand",
    "test:verbose": "jest --passWithNoTests --runInBand",
    "test:unit": "yarn test -- --watch -c jest-unit-config.ts",
    "test:integration": "yarn test -- --watch -c jest-integration-config.ts",
    "test:staged": "yarn test -- --findRelatedTest",
    "test:ci": "yarn test -- --coverage"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.13",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^22.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^4.1.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.10.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
}


//jest-config.ts

export default {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/**/protocols/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/**/*protocols.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/**/models/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/**/usecases/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/**/index.ts'
  ],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
  transform: {
    '.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest'
  }
}

// jest-mongodb-config.ts

export default {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    instance: {
      dbName: 'jest'
    },
    binary: {
      version: '4.0.3',
      skipMD5: true
    },
    autoStart: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).